# Using Gephi, how do I show nodes older than X days?

Tags: datetime, time, gephi, elapsedtime

I am using Gephi 0.8.2 Beta and I'm just beginning to use it.

I would like to add a node attribute like 'Pass Change Date' of `<datetime>` type. Then possibly create a node attribute like 'Pass elapsed time' which compares the 'Pass Change Date' to today' date to give elapsed time.

What I am looking for is a way to determine all nodes that are greater than 90 days.

Comment: Did you try anything ? Show here

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm brand new to Gephi.  I created a TimeInterval column which oddly enough I can't delete.  And there is no DateTime type.  I've switch to Excel for now but there is alot of relationship coordination I'd like to see with Gephi.  Like account name, server name, db type (like MSSQL, Oracle, etc), and environment (dev, qa, stage, prod).  I've done these all as String columns on the node.  I'm also hope I can show relationships b/w nodes based on having a similar values in a coiumn - But I don't know if that's how to use Gephi.

Comment: This is only possible programmatically. I don't know of any way to extract current time as a value, using the gui